# why the AntiForgery token I got in authorization filter is different from the one I see in browser?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

In my application, I use *@Html.AntiForgeryToken()* to decorate the form and then I implemented a CustomAuthorizationFilter by inheriting from *IAuthorizationFilter* which has a method that checks for AntiForgery for action methods including Ajax calls.

Here is my CheckForAntiForgery method:

```
private static void CheckForAntiForgery(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    var cookie = request.Cookies["__RequestVerificationToken"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
       var cookieToken = cookie.Value;
       var formToken = request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"];
       AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }
}
```

I'm using Ajax call for a save method and send *form.serialize()* as the data. I checked in browser for the value of *$('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()*, and saw *"form.serialize()"* was picking up that value. However, when I stepped into the method above, the *'formToken'* was different from the one I saw in browser. Does the *formToken* go through some additional processing after it's sent back to application?

An additional question, on the same page, I tried multiple save clicks, while I saw that each time the value of *$('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()* changed, the *formToken* I got in the method above didn't change. Is there any reason for that, or am I missing something in my implementation of AntiForgery token check?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe __RequestVerificationToken will not change.

Below sample code that works for me in a asp.net identity login using ajax.
Hope this helps.

```
if (form.valid()) {
            $(this).addClass('ladda-button');
            var l = Ladda.create(this);
            l.start();

            var form1 = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form1).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Account/Login',
                data: {
                    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                    Email: $('#username').val(),
                    Password: $('#password').val(),
                    RememberMe: false,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.id === 1) {
                        mynotify('<div class="alert alert-success media fade in"><p><strong>success!</strong> ' + result.name + '</p></div>');
                        window.location.href = "\\";
                    } else if (result.id === 4) {
                        mynotify('<div class="alert alert-danger media fade in"><p><strong>Error!</strong> Login failed..</p></div>');
                    } else {
                        mynotify('<div class="alert alert-danger media fade in"><p><strong>Error!</strong> ' + result.name + '</p></div>');
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    mynotify('<div class="alert alert-danger media fade in"><p><strong>Error!</strong> Critical error occured, contact administrator</p></div>');
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });

            l.stop();

        } else {
            $('body').addClass('boxed');
            mynotify('<div class="alert alert-danger media fade in"><p><strong>Error!</strong> Please try again.</p></div>');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out formToken is different than the one I see in browser because the request didn't get token sent through ajax and kept using the old token. Instead of sending token in data, I moved it to the ajax beforeSend event:

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: newurl,
      beforeSend: function (request)
      {
         request.setRequestHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", token);
      },
      data: form.serialize(),
      datatype: "JSON",
      success: function..,
      error: function..
})
```

Now it's picking up the new token every time a new request is sent.